# EventLog Files - Connected app ID field is blank

Tags: connected-apps, eventlogfile

When I downloaded the event log files, almost all records with the API_FAMILY field as SOAP or REST have the CONNECTED_APP_ID field as blank. Is there any other way to get the apps related to these event log records?

Comment: Are the txns you looking to get are sent from client which made use of connected app? Note that if you login to sfdc using Soap Login api call and use that session id, there is no connected app in that context.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, I believe I read somewhere that SOAP api calls will not have a connected app ID and that only REST will have one. I was hoping that there was another way to see where these calls were coming from, but it seems like there might not be.